# Geany unable to execute Python

Tags: python, windows-7, geany

I'm not a great coder, in fact I'm just trying to learn, but I can't get Geany to regonise Python in my system (Windows 7) when I try to execute the program. When I click Execute, it opens a command prompt saying:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14):

Add the Python executable to your PATH. For example, I have Python installed at:

```
C:\Program Files\Python 3.2
```

So press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>, and go to "Advanced System Settings":

[image: System settings]

Click "Environment Variables" at the bottom, add a new user variable called `PYTHONDIR`, and set it to your Python installation directory:

[image: Adding a new environment variable]

Then, look for another variable there called `PATH`. If there isn't one, create one and give it the value `%PYTHONDIR%`; otherwise, append `;%PYTHONDIR` to the existing one. It should work fine now.

[image: Adding the PYTHONDIR to the PATH variable]

Answer (score 4):

Or you can skip the New User Variable. Find the PATH variable and click Edit. You want to add `;C:\Python27` to the end of that string. Save your change.

via:
http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that setting the path as described in the other prior posts was necessary but not sufficient.  In my case, I had saved my script to the "geany" directory.  It turns out that there was a permissions problem with the geany editor trying to create a temporary file in the geany folder.  As soon as I saved my script to another folder the permissions error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. Added python to PATH, working fine on cmd. But Geany wasn't able to execute. Turns out, while saving the file, I had not entered .py as extension. Once I did it, worked fine.